# Errors after upgrading from winsock.h to winsock2.h

Tags: c, sockets, visual-studio-2012

I have a program in C that redirects tcp ports. i was using `winsock.h` previously and the application worked fine.

I have now included winsock2.h instead of `winsock.h` to get advanced functions like `WSAioctl()` which were not available in `winsock.h`.

I have included the `winsock2.h` in the right order, that is, before `windows.h` so that the `windows.h` does not include the `winsock.h`. I have also tried other methods of avoiding `winsock.h` and `winsock2.h` conflicts that is defining `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before `windows.h`.

I have also linked the `ws2_32.lib` instead of `wsock32.lib`.

**Problem:** The application successfully builds with `winsock2.h` without errors but when i run the program in debug mode (or otherwise), it crashes and triggers several breakpoints one of which is at `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer()`.
What could be the possible reason for these exceptions?

Platform: VS2012 on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with Winsock (unless your code is simply using Winsock2 functions incorrectly to begin with)  Something else is going on.  Since you are seeing a *runtime* error, what line of code is raising the error?

Comment: I get the following error when i try to close the socket using `closesocket(s)`.

Error:

`HEAP[rinetd.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00470000, 004B47A0 )
rinetd.exe has triggered a breakpoint.`

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the error.